# Lightweight ComboBox for Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, combobox

I'm looking for a lightweight ComboBox for as3. The normal ComboBox component introduces an overhead of 60kb, that's too much for a banner or a landing page.
 I google this looking for options but what I found are paid custom components.
Do you know where I can find a lightweight combobox for as3?

Thanks in advance,
   Jonathan.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an open source component that is suppose to be lighter than the stock ones:
http://www.bytearray.org/?p=137

Comment: It's somewhat lighter - but the minimum still looks like about 55kb. It actually uses fl.core.ComponentShim from CS3 which adds almost as much as the full CS3 components :-(